# Why is my cordless rumblepad 2 gamepad not being detected?

Tags: pc, controllers, tomb-raider-2013

I have cordless rumblepad 2 and I want to play with it in tomb raider. But the problem is that although I can perform actions like jumping and play with it the tutorial shows the keyboard and mouse buttons and I also can't change the buttons arranged for the controller. There is also the problem that I can't look around with the controller.

So my questions are

1.Why doen't the game recognise the gamepad as the way I want to play and only show its buttons

2.How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many games are made to be used with xbox controllers. To get Tomb Raider 2013 working with a Logitech Rumblepad 2 or Dual Action Gamepad, all you need to do is to download the xbox360 gamepad emulator, which is a small tool to let a game think your logitech is a xbox360 controller. It is a free tool which also works with other games. Download and open either [this](http://www.tankkill.valkvideos.nl/xbox360cemulator.v.3.0.rar)
or [this](http://xinput.googlecode.com/files/xbox360cemu.v.3.0.rar).Extract all 5 files and copy them into the folder where the game was installed. For Tomb Raider that's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Square Enix\TombRaider`. If you have trouble locating the game folder, try searching for `TombRaider.exe`and place the 5 files in the same directory as that executable file. That's it! To test your new xbox 360 gamepad emulator click `XInputTest.exe`

P.S.: If Lara looks up & looks down are switched in the game open the button settings file `xbox360cemu.ini` and edit the line `Right Analog` so that it says `Right Analog Y=6`
***UPDATE:***
For a STEAM installed game its in a folder like `C:\Program Files(..)\Steam\steamapps\common\TombRaider` OR search for `TombRaider.exe`. Thanks @MBreadley.

Comment: You don't seem to be accounting for a Steam install.  I would be surprised if the install wasn't under the Steam directory.

Answer (score 0):

Tomb Raider only really has full support for an Xbox 360 Gamepad, Whilst it does support most game pads in "Some" fashion (finger quotes) it was only really a half arsed attempt at putting the support in by the developers.

If you've got a wireless 360 pad lying around with a play and charge kit just plug it in like you normally would and usually it installs itself straight away and should support the game natively.

I don't really know what to suggest to improve the support for your rumblepad though, You could try Pinnacle game profiler which adds controller support to non-controller games like CoD4 : MW1, You can get it from their site - http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/

UPDATE - After a quick bit of digging a lot of users are reporting success using x360ce, It's a wrapper which translates Xinput calls into DirectInput calls which are more universal, try giving that a shot - https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/downloads/list

Comment: From most games' perspectives, there is very little difference between an Xbox-360 gamepad and any other gamepad - DirectInput handles that for us.  So, there's a pretty good chance he can get his gamepad to work.  I also don't think "Use a different gamepad" answers the question regardless, so -1

Comment: I did suggest using Pinnacle profiler though which is designed to extend the capabilities of gamepads that some titles struggle with, I'm not certain whether there's a profile for the new one yet but all the other tomb raiders seem to be on the list so could be worth a shot

Comment: That software appears to be for games that don't already support a gamepad.  It also doesn't have support for the new Tomb Raider, which makes it a complete non-sequitur...

Comment: Also, a wireless Xbox controller with a play and charge kit *won't* work as a PC game pad. The cord from the play and charge kit is strictly for playing. No data is sent from the controller to the PC.

Comment: Normal wireless 360 controllers don't work on pc, even with a play and charge kit. You need an [xbox 360 wireless controller for windows](http://www.gamekool.com/images/XBOX360-wireless-controller-+-PC-receiver.jpg) or a normal wired controller. The normal wireless controllers are for the console only.